# Find wrapped strings in a pre-push git hook

Tags: bash, git, shell, git-bash, githooks

I am trying to go through the changes being made in a git push and find any instance of a wrapped string like so: `___('something to be translated')` so that I can make some subsequent API calls with that information. But for some reason I am unable to get any sort of useful output when I try to use a `git diff --cached` call. I already have my regex pattern figured out to do the search. Any suggestions on this would be great.

My code looks something like this:

```
FILES_PATTERN="/___[^)]+\)/gm"
git diff --cached --name-only | \
    grep -E $FILES_PATTERN | \
    GREP_COLOR='4;5;37;41' xargs grep --color --with-filename -n  echo 'COMMIT contains strings that need to be uploaded to Lokalise.' && exit 1
```

Comment: show what you've tried and what isn't working

Comment: @AnthonySottile I've updated it to include what I have tried.

Comment: your pattern is wrong, slashes aren't needed nor are flags -- try `echo hi | grep -E '/hi/gm'` for example vs `echo hi | grep -E hi`

Comment: Even running just this doesn't seem to be doing anything:
`git diff --cached --name-only| \
    echo 'something' | grep -E '/___[^)]+\)/gm' | \
  exit 1`

Comment: right -- because as I said above **your pattern is wrong**

Comment: My regex? I tested it on a regex tester and it seems to match the pattern I'm looking for

Comment: maybe if you're using javascript or php -- but neither of those are `grep -E` -- try the commands I wrote for you above

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. That got me closer than I was doing this:
```git diff --cached --name-only 
    echo hi | grep -E '/___[^)]+\)/gm' 
  exit 1```
But the output in the terminal is still showing up empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I think your bash script is the main issue. It's not formatted properly. This will also make it so the output will only be the modified lines in addition to the ___() matches.

```
pattern="___\([^)]+\)"
echo $(git diff $remote_sha $local_sha | grep -E $pattern | grep '^[+-]')
```

Hope this works.